# How to generate xml parser from sql query

Tags: c#

I wont to create a class library to receive input from the user, and dynamically generated the query based on the input, These queries were then forwarded to an XML parsing component, which converted both queries(user input and intended query)
into XML trees. These XML parse trees were compared parallel

Comment: OK. Do you have a question about something?

Comment: Show you expect someone to write it for you and post it here? Or you have something to ask help for?